# Responsive Theme for Magento Admin Panel

Tags: admin, rwd

I am new to Magento. I wanted to know if it is possible to create a responsive theme for Magento Admin Panel. To be clear I am not asking responsive theme for the Store Front. I know there are plenty of those available out there. I need a responsive theme for the Backend admin panel. Is it possible to create such theme? Are there any such base theme (paid or free) available out there which I can use as a starting point for customization?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by searching Magento Connect for "Responsive Admin Theme" [{{Click Here}}](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=admin%20themes&pl=0)

there will probably be one out there.  Theme Forest usually has a number of themes for Magento as well so you could check there @ [{{Theme Forest}}](http://themeforest.net/)

You can always customize the admin theme if you really know what you are doing as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think this product can suit your need [Responsive Admin Theme](http://cmsmart.net/magento-themes/magento-responsive-admin-template). I've bought it and now it's working very well. The support team is also very helpful. So I suggest.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

Magento CE 1.9 and Magento EE 1.14 have a default RWD theme for the storefront. This can save you time if you decide you want RWD for the storefront.

You might also get some general RWD ideas from there.