# Is it possible to change the Magento 2 admin panel to a responsive layout?

Tags: magento2, admin, rwd

Are there any methods or tutorials to turn magento 2.0 admin panel as a mobile responsive template?

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange :). You have to Create Admin Responsive Theme & Use It or Make Current Magento 2 Default Theme to Responsive using CSS

Comment: @AnkitShah Any links or tutorials?

Comment: ofcourse you can. But its not out of the box. you need to customize it.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/13196/responsive-theme-for-magento-admin-panel with other links https://cmsmart.net/magento-themes/magento-responsive-admin-template
http://magentoexpertforum.com/showthread.php/14436-Magento-Responsive-Admin-Theme
For Magento 1
https://github.com/jreinke/magento-admin-theme

Comment: @AnkitShah Thank you! I will check the links

Comment: @AnkitShah The problem is all the solutions are directed to version one of Magento. I wanted the solution for Magento 2.